# Why does my network connection keep disconnecting?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, kali-linux

I have successfully installed Kali Linux on my computer, but, upon installing it, I faced the problem of my network connection being extremely slow and disconnecting all the time. So I looked on the Internet and apparently my wireless card has a bad reputation with Linux.

I then decided to buy a wireless USB from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007FN9D80).

I tried it out and it it has full bars, unlike my wireless card which had only 1 bar. I went on the Internet and everything was working fine. Then, all of a sudden, my Internet just went really slow and stopped working. I couldn't connect to anything and loading would be endless. Every time this happened, I'd go to the terminal and type in:

```
systemctl restart network-manager
```

After about a few seconds of executing this command, I'd be able to connect to the Internet normally with fast speeds again. Notice when the Internet starts to slow down, the bars are still full in the wireless tab for the USB adapter. This would happen every 5-10 minutes and I would do it every 5-10 minutes. I wanted to make a cron job for this but I honestly think that's a really stupid cheap way of fixing a bigger problem.

What is happening?

If someone needs any log files, just give me the command and I'll put the output on here.

EDIT(1):
This is the dmesg command executed while network is up:
http://pastebin.com/ZvhxQGHh

Comment: dmesg usually shows wifi issues, can you copy it here?

Comment: This is the dmesg command executed while network is up:
http://pastebin.com/ZvhxQGHh

Comment: Have you seen this? Not sure if it applies in your situation, but it might help to try ...https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386925/aborting-authentication-by-local-choice-reason-3-deauth-leaving-when-trying

Comment: ... also: https://superuser.com/questions/974017/ubuntu-wlan0-authenticates-and-then-drops

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I tried to use the above solution and it didn't work for me!
I'm not sure of what was happening, but I think it's a DHCP problem. I fixed it by configuring it manually. For example:

```
$ sudo ifconfig enp4s0 192.168.42.135 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`enp4s0` is the name of the device (in that case my ethernet device).

Comment: I can add that I have had issues with NetworkManager and if you're comfortable with manual configuration and disabling NetworkManager it can be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikidevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/EDUP_EP-N8508) the possible driver is `rtl8192cu` and can be installed from backports or as [follows](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
sudo depmod -a
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

> There is a known issue with power management on some hardware. If your WiFi connection drops after a few minutes, install the following module setting file to disable power management in your WiFi interface:
>
> `sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/8192cu-disable-power-management.conf /etc/modprobe.d/`
>
> And then reboot.

Comment: I get the following error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-generic
E: Unable to locate package dkms

**AND**

cp: cannot stat ‘./rtl8192cu-fixes/8192cu-disable-power-management.conf’: No such file or directory