# "aborting authentication by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)" when trying to connect to wifi

Tags: wifi, dhcp, wlan

I installed Debian 9 stretch (GNOME desktop) 64-bit on my PC. My USB wireless adapter (TP-LINK TL-WN722N) was detected automatically after installing atheros firmware:

```
apt-get install firmware-atheros
```

But I can't connect to any wireless framework, whether they are protected with password or unprotected.

I plugged my USB. It was detected, sent auth, got authenticated, but immediately aborted authentication. Disabling IPV6 did not solve my problem..
Here is my `dmesg` report:

```
[   59.880805] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[   60.005727] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
[   60.005729] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[   60.005731] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
[   60.005732] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: ATHEROS
[   60.005734] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 12345
[   60.324981] usb 1-1.4: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[   60.325069] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[   60.348095] usb 1-1.4: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw
[   60.629962] usb 1-1.4: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[   60.880826] ath9k_htc 1-1.4:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[   61.111895] ath9k_htc 1-1.4:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[   61.111897] ath9k_htc 1-1.4:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[   61.111899] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c
[   61.111900] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   61.111901] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   61.111911] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
[   61.111912] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
[   61.111912] ath: Regpair used: 0x52
[   61.122477] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9271 Rev:1
[   61.185069] ath9k_htc 1-1.4:1.0 wlx18a6f7160a49: renamed from wlan0
[   61.224640] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18a6f7160a49: link is not ready
[   61.361032] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18a6f7160a49: link is not ready
[   61.535923] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18a6f7160a49: link is not ready
[   61.743450] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18a6f7160a49: link is not ready
[   69.190250] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18a6f7160a49: link is not ready
[   70.360621] wlx18a6f7160a49: authenticate with 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7
[   70.551637] wlx18a6f7160a49: send auth to 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7 (try 1/3)
[   70.556012] wlx18a6f7160a49: authenticated
[   75.555233] wlx18a6f7160a49: aborting authentication with 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   76.872114] wlx18a6f7160a49: authenticate with 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7
[   77.061146] wlx18a6f7160a49: send auth to 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7 (try 1/3)
[   77.065158] wlx18a6f7160a49: authenticated
[   82.061225] wlx18a6f7160a49: aborting authentication with 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   83.775718] wlx18a6f7160a49: authenticate with 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7
[   83.965040] wlx18a6f7160a49: send auth to 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7 (try 1/3)
[   83.969807] wlx18a6f7160a49: authenticated
[   88.969792] wlx18a6f7160a49: aborting authentication with 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   91.207178] wlx18a6f7160a49: authenticate with 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7
[   91.395860] wlx18a6f7160a49: send auth to 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7 (try 1/3)
[   91.400263] wlx18a6f7160a49: authenticated
[   93.996839] wlx18a6f7160a49: aborting authentication with 74:23:44:dc:0f:d7 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   94.061841] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18a6f7160a49: link is not ready
[   94.233433] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18a6f7160a49: link is not ready
```

I have no idea why this happened, nor why it was aborted multiple times in one try.

Edit: iwconfig report:

```
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx18a6f7160a49  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: How close are you from that AP

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Somehow, my firmware got trouble with long interface name. So I ran this command to prevent it:

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
```

and it worked.

Comment: Just to add up that [this article](https://major.io/2016/01/20/tinkering-with-systemds-predictable-network-names/) helped me understand *why* the fix actually works; it's because we're overriding default `/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link` file which contains a ̀`NamePolicy` which does not please the firmware. BTW, I still had problems joining some networks. It happened that the default [regulatory domain](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/crda) did not match my location, so I had to issue a `iw reg set <MyCountryCode>` and edit the `/etc/default/crda` file according

Comment: I observed the very same issue with an rt2x00 and this workaround worked immediately. I'd appreciate though if someone could explain why it works and what the proper solution is.

Comment: While I agree this is a functional workaround, it would be fantastic if someone could explain the "why" a bit better... My guess is it has to do with something in NetworkManager but that's purely a punt.

Comment: For some reason, this appears to be working on my Netgear WG111v2 (RTL 8187b chipset). However, this WiFi adapter comes and goes, so maybe I'm declaring victory too soon.

Comment: This helps, I've been fighting this issue for over a month, I upgraded my debian few months ago and started seeing this problem , but with only specific routers. I have intel wifi chip (iwlwifi module).

Comment: This works for my Ralink MTK7601u wireless adapter. `$ sudo nmcli dev wifi connect MySSID` raises an error message like `Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.` The dmesg report is almost the same.

Comment: This solution works for those using `systemd.networkd`. If your are using `NetworkManager` only, you have to write a rule at `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

Comment: Looks like interface names are handled by systemd-udevd. This strange symlink disables configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link. Empty file should work too.See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html

Comment: Worked for me in a Debian 10 using Linksys WUSB54GC. I had to unplug and plug the USB adapter for changes to take effect. Adding 'SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"' to /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules also works.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me as my wlan link name is wlan0 but I get the exact same error. I use openSUSE 15.4 with Gnome (latest)

Answer (score 10):

As others said the issue is caused by non-standard name the device gets (i.e. not wlan*). Linking /dev/null did not work for me, so I had to create a udev rule to rename the interface:

In

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

add:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?\*", ATTRS{product}=="802.11 n WLAN", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
```

Adjust `ATTRS{product}` to your specific device. [Check how to find it here](https://weinimo.github.io/how-to-write-udev-rules-for-usb-devices.html)

Comment: I'm having this same issue, and am just coming across this solution ... Is it only `ATTRS{product}` that needs to be replaced? Does `DRIVERS` also need to have something there or is it actually supposed to be set to `=?` Thanks!

Comment: Did it over a year ago and frankly don't remember the details. I believe ATTRS{product} should be enough to match your device. Also, it should be DRIVERS=="?*" - stack ate the star.

Comment: the links is broken!

Comment: This is the solution for those who are using NetworkManager. This rule can be more flexible so that you don´t have to care about the `ATTRS{product}`. Mine is woking with this configuration: `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"`

Answer (score 5):

As others said, the issue is caused by non-standard name the device gets (i.e. not wlan*). Below is the proper ways to set the name of the network interface when using **systemd.networkd** or **NetworkManager**.

**systemd.networkd**

While linking to `/dev/null` may solve the problem, the proper way is to create a `.link file` setting the device name.

Create `/etc/systemd/network/50-wlan.link` with the following content:

```
[Match]
Type=wlan

[Link]
Name=wlan0
```

Reboot or restart the network then check the result: `udevadm info /sys/class/net/wlan0 | grep ID_NET_NAME=`

More details and debug information can be found here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html

**NetworkManager**

When using NetworkManager the interface rename can be achieved by creating a rule at the /etc/udev/rules.d directory.

Create `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-rename-wlan.rules` with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

If everything went right you should see `wlan0` among your devices after a `reboot`.

```
root@bananapi:~# ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group 
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group
```

And you be able to connect to the wifi using `nmcli d wifi connect MEU_WIFI_SSID password MEU_PASSWORD`. The `nmcli` will persist the connection and reconnect after a reboot.

Comment: I think neither NetworkManager nor systemd-networkd renames your device. That is done by udev. So, yes, writing a udev rule works and so does creating a .link file (in that case, the .link file is processed by udev, not systemd-networkd).

Comment: In the second example its clear that the udev is getting the job done, not NetworkManager. You may be right tough, but in the second example systemd-networkd can get the job done as well (perhaps it talks to udev under the hood).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works for me too. But I am not sure, that using a link to /dev/null is the best solution, cause in 3 or 4 months I will be very confused finding such a link in this place.

In the *Raspbian*-Installation on my Raspberry Pi I found a regular file /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link with the following content:

```
# This machine is most likely a virtualized guest, where the old persistent
# network interface mechanism (75-persistent-net-generator.rules) did not work.
# This file disables /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link to avoid
# changing network interface names on upgrade. Please read
# /usr/share/doc/udev/README.Debian.gz about how to migrate to the currently
# supported mechanism.
```

I use this regular file instead of the symbolic link to fix the problem. I think this solution has the advantage that there is some sort of documentation on the system (perhaps I should add a link to this page…).

This will give a hint of what is going on to future-me. >;->

Answer (score -1):

Accepted solution did not work for me.

I have solved the problem by disabling IPv6 in the connection properties.
Run **nm-connection-editor**, select your troubled connection, press the button with the gear icon (in my case), go to the "IPv6 Settings" tab, in the field Method select "Ignore" option.