# My wlan0 connection drops ~ every 5 minutes. Using USB and rtl8192cu. Where to find log info and how to fix?

Tags: wifi, logs

I'm finishing setting up a used laptop (ca. 2015?) with a pretty current version of Debian.  I have a USB wifi device that worked with a Raspberry Pi a few years ago.  It's an rtl8192cu.  To get it to work initially I had to follow the advice [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386925/aborting-authentication-by-local-choice-reason-3-deauth-leaving-when-trying), using

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
```

Now, it comes up, but after about 5 minutes it drops. However, running ip statistics continues to list wlan0 as UP with no dropped packets.  The Gnome status bar still shows a connection.  However ping says Destination Host Unreachable. And, if the IP statistics are always up to date, about 300 packets are received without errors from probably Youtube after a ping fails.

Pulling out the USB stick and reinserting brings it back up.

I've looked at dmesg and /var/log/syslog for clues.  There isn't anything obvious, but one odd thing is when the USB stick is plugged in, it tries one firmware, fails, tries a second firmware, fails, tries the second firmware again and succeeds.

Is there another log I should look at?
Any idea how I might prevent these drops or at least make recovery quick and effortless?

Comment: Realtek sucks, if that's an external USB get something better. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter-realtek/252215